# Creating a pause in a for loop in Tkinter

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

In this situation, I want to iterate `self.players` twice. For each iteration, I want to pause for 1 sec before calling the print method. How can I get his to work?
Here is a simplified example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.players = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        self.play()

    def play(self):
        for x in range(2):
            for player in self.players:
                self.after(1000, self.print, player)

    def print(self, player):
        print(player)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: You are looping through all of the players (twice), and scheduling them to be printed one second later.  In other words, they will all be printed at exactly the same time!  You either need to: 1) use an increasing delay for each item, or 2) schedule only one thing, which will itself schedule the next thing when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Control the counter directly
2. `self.after` should be calling the `play` method, not the `print` method

   ```
   import tkinter as tk

   class Main(tk.Tk):
       def __init__(self):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
            self.counter=0
            self.players = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            self.after(1000,self.play)

      def play(self):
            if self.counter<2:
                for player in self.players:
                    (self.print(player))
                self.counter+=1
                self.after(1000,self.play)

      def print(self, player):
            print(player)

   if __name__ == '__main__':
      Main()
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't wait one second before outputting to the screen.